'Unknown Error' occurring randomly when making SQL database queries
I was playing around trying to make a game in the browser that uses an Azure SQL server to have some basic multiplayer (like chat messages or item trading), but I've run into an issue where randomly (like 50% of requests, mostly with trying to select player equipment, but also sometimes with getting messages or, in this case, getting the player's level) the pymssql connection craps out and refuses to send any more request due to an "Unknown error" the full code is available here: https://github.com/Edspeedy1/Server-Hosted-Website/blob/main/server.py
Error message:
Error:  (0, b'Unknown error') 
---------------------------------------- 
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50549) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_pymssql.pyx", line 447, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_mssql.pyx", line 1125, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_mssql.pyx", line 1156, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_mssql.pyx", line 1289, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_mssql.pyx", line 1852, in pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_mssql.pyx", line 1898, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException 
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (0, b'Unknown error') 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 691, in process_request_thread 
    self.finish_request(request, client_address) 
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request 
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self) 
  File "c:\Users\Eric\code\Server Hosted Website\server.py", line 158, in __init__ 
    super().__init__(request, client_address, server) 
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 671, in __init__ 
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 755, in __init__ 
    self.handle() 
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 436, in handle 
    self.handle_one_request() 
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 424, in handle_one_request 
    method() 
  File "c:\Users\Eric\code\Server Hosted Website\server.py", line 196, in do_POST 
    self.get_basic_user_data(username) 
  File "c:\Users\Eric\code\Server Hosted Website\server.py", line 220, in get_basic_user_data 
    tempPlayerData = self.send_SQL_query('SELECT * FROM basicPlayerData where username = %s', (username,), DB_CONN, get=True, fetchAll=False) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Eric\code\Server Hosted Website\server.py", line 321, in send_SQL_query 
    raise e 
  File "c:\Users\Eric\code\Server Hosted Website\server.py", line 311, in send_SQL_query 
    cursor.execute(query, params) 
  File "src\\pymssql\\_pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute 
pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError: (0, b'Unknown error') 
----------------------------------------

and here is the code that does the SQL requests:
    def send_SQL_query(self, query, params, db, get=False, fetchAll=True):
        try:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query, params)
            if get:
                if fetchAll:
                    return cursor.fetchall()
                else:
                    return cursor.fetchone()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: ", e)
            global DB_CONN
            # re-establish connection since the old one in no longer usable (just keeps saying unknown error)
            DB_CONN = pymssql.connect(server=server,user=user,password=password,database=database)
            raise e
        finally:
            if not get:
                db.commit()
            cursor.close()

the problem occurs at random times on mostly the select requests that get sent but has been noticed on insert requests as well. The issue was super hard to replicate until I added a new table called playerEquipment and now it's appearing like 10x more often. Once the "unknown error" has occurred, then any future SQL queries sent will runn into the same error, but if I redo the connection with DB_CONN = pymssql.connect(server=server,user=user,password=password,database=database) then the issue seems to clear up for the next 2-3 requests until eventually failing again due to "unknown error".

Do you reuse same connection for all requests? I dunno if you have some multithreading going on, but i think connection isn't thread safe. Perhaps you need some sort of connection cool

@siggemannen we all want a cool connection

your right, I do have another thread that's using the same connection (start_inactivity_check) however giving that thread its own connection doesn't solve the problem and that thread only uses that connection once an hour, I'll look into the threading stuff more though

@siggemannen the server does use a threadedHTTPServer
class ThreadedHTTPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):     pass
this was causing problems, any way to keep the threading behavior but give each thread its own DB connection?

It appears like there was some multithreading going on on the socket server that was causing problems, since the inventory page had some images it was almost guarantied that another thread would need to be opened up to handle the message polling. I wished the error message actually told me that it was a thread issue, but oh well.
Simple fix:
class CustomRequestHandler(RangeHTTPServer.RangeRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        # individual connection per instance of the request handler instead of 1 global connection
        self.DB_CONN = pymssql.connect(server=serverConnection, user=user, password=password, database=database) 
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server)


Glad you solved it, although i would advice against 1 thread = 1 connection, that can saturate the server, especially if you have a lot of threads, better using pooling, although i'm not a python expert, so i cannot recommend a pool implementation. Perhaps check out pyodbc as well, it's a bit more official than pymssql these days for SQL Server
